# How can I keep lizards away from my room?

Tags: pest-control

How can I keep lizards away from my room? I live in a hostel and I do not want to kill them. Is there a drug that can just repel them?

Comment: Tell us where you live (country, state?) and what kind of lizards they are.

Comment: @Josh 
I live in Malaysia, after I googled I found it belongs to geckos family, small lizards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Get a [cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat)

[image: Cat]

## Get them [jobs](http://www.indeed.com/worldwide)

I've heard they tend to enjoy selling insurance.
[image: Geico]

## [Mothballs?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mothball)

Mothballs seem to be a popular recommendation.
[image: Mothballs]

## [Garlic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garlic): Not just for Dracula anymore.

Ever since [Twilight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Saga_(film_series)), garlic has lost popularity as a vampire deterrent. Give it new life as a lizard repellent.
[image: Garlic]

## [Onions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion)

They keep my boss away, maybe they'll keep lizards away too.
[image: Onion]

## Call [Captain Kirk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_T._Kirk)

[image: Captain Kirk]

Comment: This gave me a good chuckle

Comment: Your first two are missing links, incomplete answer.

Comment: @Jason Fixed...

Comment: Unfortunately, the cat answer works, felines enjoy a good hunt. I say unfortunately, because the geckos et al. can also come in quite handy to get rid of mosquitos and the like. So I guess the choice is up to you: either the lizards, or the cats (and the mozzies).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the layout of your living space, introducing a Teflon-coated vertical/overhanging barrier may hinder their approach.

Wikipedia does not list any repellants for the Gecko infraorder, but you may be able to find more information if you can identify the species.